# ROR + Integer Value Convert Into Different Format Of Currency

Tags: javascript, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Here, Change the format of Integer

```
1234567890 => 1.234.567.890 using ruby function.

1234567890.12 => 1.234.567.890.12 using ruby function.
```

Now Please suggest something. And also function to convert the currency format in DKK (Danish Currency).

Answer (score 0):

To display currency nicely in your view number_to_currency is a handy part of ActiveSupport: http://ap.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#M000367

Answer (score 0):

This method will help you.

```
str = '123456780009090990.20'
counter = 0
str1 = ''
str.reverse.each_char do |c|
  str1 += c
  str1 += '.' if counter == 3
  counter = (c == '.' || counter == 3) ? 0 : counter + 1
end
puts str1.reverse
```

See number_to_currency method.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#M001684